# Confusion variable/function despite working code?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have the following block of code, I want the window to close after an option has been chosen. It works, and the code works the way I intend it to. However, when the window closes, it returns the error code
"sg.WIN_CLOSED()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" which I understand is because I am mixing variables and functions, but I do not understand the error, as the code is working?

Any ideas are appreciated! I am a beginner at Python.

```
    options = ['Go on date', 'Stay in']

    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Choose one->"),
         sg.Listbox(options, select_mode=sg.LISTBOX_SELECT_MODE_SINGLE, size=(50, len(options)))],
        [sg.Button("Date"), sg.Button("Stay in")]
    ]

    # Create the Window
    window = sg.Window("Question", layout)

    # Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the input
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        print(f"event={event}")
        if event is None or event == "Date" or event == "Stay in": # if user closes window or clicks cancel
            break

    if event == "Date":
        print("Let's go on a date!")
        # close  the window
        sg.WIN_CLOSED()

    else:
        print('Lets stay in')
        sg.popup(f"You selected to stay in")
        # close  the window
        sg.WIN_CLOSED()
```

Comment: Just delete the lines `sg.WIN_CLOSED()`

Comment: That's not how you close a window - it's `window.close()`.

Comment: You are basically trying to execute the statement `None()`.  Running `None()` produces the same error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`